# Combining 2 columns in MySQL table to create a new one with a specific string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date, select

I have the following columns in my table:

```
launch_month    Years   
Jun             2018    
July            2018    
Aug             2018
```

I want to create a new column called 'launch_id' and combine the other 2 columns into a string of '201806', so the above would look like:

```
launch_month    Years   launch_id
Jun             2018    201806
July            2018    201807
Aug             2018    201808
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a `case` expression:

```
select
    launch_month,
    years,
    years * 100 + case launch_month
        when 'Jan' then  1
        when 'Feb' then  2
        when 'Mar' then  3
        ...
        when 'Dec' then 12
    end launch_id
from mytable
```

This generates a new *numeric* column called `launch_id`, that represents the date in format `YYYYMM`.

Alternatively, you can use date functions (but this might be less efficient):

```
select 
    launch_month,
    years,
    date_format(
        str_to_date(concat('01', launch_month, years), '%d%b%Y'),
        '%Y%m'
    ) launch_id
from mytable
```

This generates a string result. If you want a number, you can just convert it, either explicitly (`cast()`) or implicitly ( `+ 0`).